Why do instantons have zero energy?
In deriving the Euclidean action for an instanton it is stated that energy is conserved along the classical path; this makes sense simply using our classical intuition for how particles behave on the classical path. In Euclidean space this means that the equations of motion are:
$$-\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx_c}{d \tau} \right)^2 + V(x_c) = E$$
with E held constant. In deriving the formula for the action however $$S = \int_{-\frac{T}{2} }^{\frac{T}{2}}{d \tau \left[\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx_c}{d \tau} \right)^2 + V(x_c) \right]} = \int_{- \frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}{ d \tau \left( \frac{dx_c}{d \tau} \right)^2 = 2 \int_{0}^{a}{\left[   dx_c \frac{d \tau}{d x_c}  \left( \frac{dx_c}{d \tau} \right)^2  \right]}} = 2 \int_{0}^{a}{\sqrt{2V(x_c)} dx }$$
It uses the equivalence $V(x_c) = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{x_c})^2$ which only holds if E = 0. Why can we say this? Does this formula not only hold in very specific cases? Thank you

It is stated where? Which eqs? Which pages?

Specifically I was following the derivation via [This Lecture][1]
[1]: https://theblackhole.pk/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Instanton-Physics-Lecture-2.pdf  by Dr. Hoodbhoy, in which he states that we choose the energy to be zero but then goes on to use the result in the general case. In S. Coleman this formula is also used for the tunneling coefficient citing Banks, Bender, and Wu's 2nd paper on Coupled Anharmonic Oscillators in the unequal mass case. In S. Coleman this is on Pg.6 of Fate of the False Vacuum I.

@AdamP The action or energy of an instanton is two times the integral over the potential. We integrate this from one minimum to the other. Your formula is wrong. I am not sure were the square root comes from. You simply replace the time derivative in the first row according to the Bogomolny equation.

Hi Adam P. This doesn't seem to be on pg.6. Which eqs?

One usually uses instantons to calculate the properties of the ground state, which actually most contribute to the action - this means that the trajectory connects the (unstable) stationary points (in inverted potential), i.e., the points where all the energy is potential, while the kinetic energy is zero: $V(0)=E$. This means that the two integrals (rather than the two integrands) in the action are equal - I think this can actually be traced to the virial theorem.

Exactly. Bogomolny used the virial theorem to derive his first order equations.
